# Best unobtrusive way to add JQuery confirm to an arbitrary element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, confirm

I'm new to jquery, and am looking for a good unobtrusive way to add a jquery replacement for javascript "confirm" to a HTML elements.  Specifically I want to be able to use it for ASP.NET Buttons, LinkButtons, ImageButtons, HyperLink etc, which client-side means any of:

```
<input type="submit"... />
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack... />
<input type="image"... />
... etc ...
```

A solution I've come up with is to add a custom attribute to the ASP.NET server control (and hence to the client element), e.g.:

```
<asp:ImageButton ... data-confirmPrompt="OK to delete customer 123?" ... />
```

which renders as:

```
<input type="image" data-confirmPrompt="OK to delete customer 123?" ... />
```

I then just need to add a click handler for elements that have this custom attribute.  The following example uses [jquery-impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/), but the same principle works with any of the jquery modal dialog implementations:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-confirmPrompt]").click(function (event) {
        var confirmPrompt = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-confirmPrompt'].value;
        event.preventDefault();
        $.prompt(confirmPrompt, {
            buttons: { Yes: true, No: false },
            callback: function (v, m, f) {
                if (v) {
                    // User clicked Yes.  Unbind handler to avoid
                    // recursion, then click the target element again
                    $(event.currentTarget).unbind('click');
                    event.currentTarget.click();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This all seems to work fine on IE8 with XHTML 1.0 Strict.  So my questions are:

1. Will all modern browsers accept custom attributes like this?
2. I understand this is not strictly standard compliant.  Can anyone suggest an standards-compliant alternative that is at least as unobtrusive and easy to use?

**UPDATE** added `data-` prefix to custom attribute, which I understand at least makes it HTML5 compliant.

**UPDATE 2** See [this follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105556/how-do-i-explicitly-execute-default-action-from-jquery-event/8135983#8135983) for an improved solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `data-` attribute, see [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

```
<a href='#' data-confirm="Are you sure?">Some Link</a>
```

Comment: +1 thanks.  And it seems IE8 supports the HTML5 doctype, so I assume the same is the case for any modern browser, right?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer to 1**: Yes they will.

**Answer to 2**: You could add CSS class called ***requires-confirm*** and add `data-description` or `data-meta` attribute with additional text that you'd use in your handler.

### Why both?

In case you have more than one functionality integrated in your page. CSS class tells which functionality should be added and `data-` attribute holds metadata to use.

If you'll only be using one single functionality, you can easily omit CSS reference and just use the `data-` attribute of course.

Comment: but dont forget adding custom attributes will cause huge performance overhead.Instead of that use jquery's data.

Comment: +1 Thanks, the data- prefix makes it HTML5 compliant, but not earlier XHTML, right? I don't understand why you suggest using a CSS class, why not just check for the custom data- prefixed attribute as in my updated question?

Comment: @sathis, can you elaborate - how can I use jquery data to get a similar unobtrusive result?  E.g. in an ASP.NET GridView, each row might have a "Delete" button with a different prompt.

Comment: @Joe: That is correct. but you could reuse `data-description` with other things as well. Not just the confirmation functionality. Hence the CSS reference. Or add an additional `data-` attribute. Or in case you only have one single functionality like this, omit CSS reference.

Answer (score 0):

personally, I use a specific **class** for things like that.

The main reason is that they are easy to select with something like `$('.confirm').each()` or better `$('.confirm').youConfirmPlugin()`. Moreover, a css is easily added in a css file (where it belongs).

if extra data is needed, then yes, use the data attribute in *combination* with the class.

Comment: But the specific class doesn't provide the prompt text.  I guess it could be done by adding the prompt text to a class and extracting using jquery metadata, but that seems harder to use by by ASP.NET developers than simply adding a custom attribute to the markup.

Comment: I did edit my answer, just not in time... concerning asp.net, I frankly don't know. I was speaking purely from the jquery standpoint.

Comment: Why do you suggest using the data attribute in combination with a class?  I don't see that selecting all elements with a data attribute - `$('[data-confirm]')` is harder than selecting with a class `$('.confirm')` - or is there a performance difference?

Comment: Performance, unification of method, but mainly... it *feels* cleaner in my eyes. That's the definitive argument huh? nah, more seriously, with a class you can use jquery class specific functions like .hasClass(), .toggleClass(), .addClass() and .removeClass(), which can come quite handy, quite often.